# Regular expression to remove characters other than number and allow single decimal dot only in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have read similar questions and no solutions seem to be working for this.
I have a Angular material input box. The input should receive only numbers and a decimal dot. All other characters should be identified and removed on keypress removal.

This is my code:

In TS file and html:

```js
allownumbersonly(inputVal) {
    inputVal = inputVal.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');//Modified after responses from stack overflow.
    this.myForm.controls['inNum'].setValue(inputVal);
  }
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
            <input id="inputNumber" matInput (keyup)="allownumbersonly($event.target.value)" placeholder="enter a number"
              formControlName="inNum">
          </mat-form-field>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Setting the `input` element `type` attribute to `number` will prevent the user from entering invalid characters. Does that work for you?

Comment: Hi, Anonta, using input type as number is a good way, ofcourse. I was looking into a regexp modification if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `keypress` event:

```
<input (keypress)="isNumberKey($event)"/>
```

and typescript:

```
isNumberKey(evt){
      console.log(evt.keyCode);
      let charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
      if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
        && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
          return false;

      return true;
   }
```

[Work example can be seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-tyzsry?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the demo for what you need. Easy and simple regex.

```js
function myFunction(){
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
demo.value = demo.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="demo" onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

Comment: Does not allow a decimal dot to be added.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Komal. But I am afraid, this does not allow decimal points

Comment: Thank you for the answer Komal! I have modified question slightly. Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use the regex in ng-pattern itself:

`<input type="number" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern="/[^0-9.]/g" required>`